# wordpress upload cv file in a registration form

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, send

i made a registration form in my website and i need to make the one who register to upload his CV

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file_cv" />
```

i need when he uploads it send the file to the server and returns a link so it can be put in the database as a string

Answer (score 0):

returns a link ? It does not work that way...you can use move_uploaded_file function to move incoming temp file to a directory you choose and use the file name to store it to DB...